# Problem with Kalman filtering accelerometer data

Tags: matlab, kalman-filters

I'm having some trouble implementing a Kalman filter in MATLAB. I have an Android phone connected sending data from accelerometer for 10 seconds. After i have the data I take out the x-axis vector. What I want after that is to get better readings using the Kalman filter.

The output I am looking for is both the acceleration and the velocity of the phone. When I run the code I get almost no change in acceleration (is between -0.5 and 0.5 m/s^2) and way to much change in velocity (increasing to very high numbers). The tests I have been running are when the phone is laying still on a table. So the correct values in acceleration and velocity should be 0.

**The problem is that since i'm only measuring acceleration my state vector will be the same vector as the measurement vector with the only difference that i also have velocity in the state vector. Both the control input is the acceleration and the measurement is the acceleration.**

So when I update my state vector the difference that is going to be multiplied with the Kalman gain is always zero.

**So my question is: Should the measurement noise / the process noise be added to the measured acceleration "z" or should the noise be added to the state prediction vector?**

Answer (score 2):

If there is any offset in the acceleration measurement, then a Kalman filter won't help without the addition of some velocity and/or position reference measurements.  Double integration of random-walk noise in the acceleration measurement will eventually lead to a reported position of your device outside the solar system.

Comment: So what you are saying is that i need some other way (other sensor(s)) to measure the velocity/position? 

How can i do that with an android phone. I only want to measure small movements so GPS can probably not be used. 
Is there any other sensor I can use: magnetometer, gyroscope etc. 

I only want to measure velocity in x and y axis and the accelerometer gives a noisy measurement going between about -0.5 and 0.5 m/s^2 when it is laying still on a table. Is Kalman filtering the way to go for correct measurements?

Comment: You can see plots of the data and code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672256/having-problems-with-kalman-filter-with-accelerometer-data-in-matlab